# Reading\Writing Binary File with char's and float's

Tags: c, binary

I am pretty new to C and like the tittle says I am trying to write a simple program to read and write files in binary. The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    FILE *fd = fopen("binFile.bin", "wb");

    if(fd == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open/create file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char buff1[] = "#This is a comment.\n";
    fwrite(buff1,1,sizeof(buff1),fd);
    char buff2[] = "#This is another comment.\n";
    fwrite(buff2,1,sizeof(buff2),fd);

    int i;
    float f[3];

    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        f[0] = i-1;
        f[1] = i;
        f[2] = i+1;

        fwrite(f,sizeof(f),1,fd);
    }

    fclose(fd);

    fd = fopen("binFile.bin", "rb");

    if(fd == NULL){
        printf("Failed to read file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char buff[100];

    do{
        fread(buff,1,sizeof(buff),fd);
        printf("%s",buff);
    }
    while(!feof(fd));

    fclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it only prints:

```
#This is a comment.
```

I know I am not using a bunch of checks for the file; however, I think the problem is that I am trying to read char's and float's with the same buffer since using the same code just for char's (or just float's) works just fine. I am guessing I have to somehow know where the bytes of char's end and the float's begin to adjust my buffer size/type accordingly.

I hope I explain myself sufficiently. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `printf("%s",buff); ` will print `buff` until the first zero it is encountered

Comment: Check the return value from `fread(buff,1,sizeof(buff),fd);`, likely about 55.  Code never attempts to `fread()` again. Thus only 1 output from "#This" to ".\n\0".

Comment: for readability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and in-indent before every closing brace '}'.   A 0 return value indicates that the code ran successfully, however it did not run successfully if unable to open the output or open the input file.  In those cases, an error indication needs to be returned .  Suggest using -1 for the error condition.

Comment: regarding these calls to fwrite().  'fwrite(f,sizeof(f),1,fd);'  the second parameter should indicate the size of the thing to write.  the third parameter should indicate how many of the second parameter to write.  for clarity, suggest: 'fwrite(f,sizeof(float),3,fd);'

Comment: Minor: @user3629249 Good to use something better than  `fwrite(f,sizeof(f),1,fd)`.  I would suggest `fwrite(f,sizeof f[0], sizeof f /sizeof f[0] ,fd)` instead.  No need to look at `f[]` declaration (other than to know it is an array) to know the size of type is right and the entire array is being written.

Comment: the function feof() should not be used for loop control,  it only is 1 if the code tried to read past the end of the input file.  suggest modifying the loop to: while( fread(buff, strlen(buff)+1, 1,fd) { printf( "%s", buff ); }   Note: this will only work properly for the first two lines in the input file.  Thereafter, the contents are the binary values of the float variables and will result in printing garbage.

Comment: @chux, I agree, but I did not want to overload the OP with info that they may not understand

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I formatted the post as per _user3629249_  recommendations. Now I think I understand why the program was failing to read the char's binary part. However, the reading of the float's binaries still remains. Does anybody know if this can be done? I know a simple solution would be to put all the comments in one file and the float's in another but I think there has to be a way to do it in just one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your binary file

[image]

As you can see there is a null terminator at byte *14h*, just after "*This is a comment.\n*" string.

This is because you use `sizeof(buff1)` on an array of char initialized with a string literal, such literals **always include the null terminator**.

**Also note** that you are storing floating point numbers is binary format, if your system use IEEE754 (mine does), when you write *-1* is encoded as `0bf800000h`.
This result in having bytes of value 0 in the file, such bytes will be interpreted as null terminators too.

Comment: Thanks! That almost took care of everything. I did look at the hex dump before posting but did't notice the terminator '\0'. Now I got it to print all of the text but when I get to the floats it is printing gibberish. Does this have to do with what you said about the encoding or is it a format issue?